# How does transplanting different sets of Sharingan eyes work?

Tags: naruto

I know the details of those eyes, I know their combination gives birth to the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan. When Madara was almost blind Izuna gave him his eyes, the same thing happened with Itachi and Sasuke.

In these two cases we've seen the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan and here comes my question:

1. In the first case, Madara was "blind" and Izuna had the good eyes, the combination was the Eternal. In the second case, Itachi was "blind" and Sasuke had the full eyes, giving birth to the Eternal. So it's indifferent which eye it's transplanted in the host body? (It doesn't matter that the good eye gets a disadvantaged blind eye?)
2. As for the main question, how it is realized the "fusion" of 2 different eyes in one eye hole? I don't want to dig myself into the nerve/artery things. I'm interested more likely in the fact that how you mix 2 eyes into one and how the full eye and the blind eye, it's yet so much stronger??

Answer (score 6):

After quite some searching I came to the sad conclusion there is barely any information available on how the 2 eyes get fused. Then again we can make some educated guesses thanks to some of the shown footage in the anime.

In episode 136 Itachi shows Sasuke how Madara got his Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan (EMS). Showing the following picture

[image: EMS Fusion]

With this image we can deduce that the old eyes are not removed from the body, meaning there are 2 pairs of eyes in the body from that moment on. The most plausible reason to pass would be that the 2 eyes fuse in a similar way as to an artificial limb getting attached to a body. This would also explain the reason for blood ties as your body might reject people who are not directly blood linked.

This would also answer your first point, as the eyes fuse it does not matter whether the begin point was the blind eye or the still functioning eye as they will become one after all

How do the eyes exactly fuse? and how do they put 2 pairs of eyes in a body to begin with? Guess this is a sort of anime magic which is not really uncommon in Naruto to begin with (small sample **(careful contains spoilers if not up to date with manga)**

> [image: Sakura using Medical Ninjutsu on Naruto]

Comment: even without the spoiler part, it's a good answer(even if it's theory)...I'm truly sad, that the mechanism of such a dojutsu isn't explained properly...still,+1 ^_^

Comment: hey! I have one question. Madara gave his eyes to Nagato and transplanted another pair of eyes into his own...ill those eyes automatically awaken mangekyo as Madara already had it? And will those eyes have the ability to make that gigantic Susano or can it only make a normal sized susano?

Answer (score 2):

The eyes are completely swapped. Sasuke even says Itachi's eyes "fit nicely" at one point in the manga. The transplantee's eyes are removed and replaced with eyes from the donor. Then some bullshit-no-jutsu happens and the eyes take on properties of both their original owner and the person they've been transplanted into. Perhaps because the blood of the recipient flows into the new eyes causing the DNA to merge or something. But anyways the eyes are swapped not fused. That's how transplants work. You replace whatever you're transplanting.

Comment: You know the source of a Sharingan is the Chakra of the brain of the user, and that Sharingan can be transplanted, and still keep their Sharingan form and powers (*cough* Kakashi *cough*). Itachis/Izuna's Mangekyou when transplanted looses no power at all, but then the new owner sends the same chakra that makes their own Sharingan into the eyes, and the 2 chakras fuse. Itachi's/Izuna's Sharingan Chakra in the eye, and Sasuke's/Madara's chakra from their own bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Over time, use of the Mangekyō Sharingan's techniques deteriorates the user's eyesight to the point of blindness. Only by taking and transplanting the eyes of another Uchiha clan member can the vision be restored, a process that results in the creation of an Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan.

> **The tighter the blood ties are between the "donor" and the receiver, the better it is for compatibility, siblings for example.**

The time from fusing the donor's Mangekyō with the receiver's Mangekyō to the point of full recovery is at least several days **in the case of Sasuke**.

Not only does this process permanently restore one's eyesight, but it also gives the person even greater power. The Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan also changes form from the original, with what appears to be a fusion of the current owner's Mangekyō with the previous owner's.

Source:-[**Source**](http://narutofanon.wikia.com/wiki/Eternal_Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan)

**EDIT**

For better understanding let me give you an instance. MS happens when a person kills someone very close to him/her. So the 'tamui' of the Sharingan changes on its own[**how tamui changes it's pattern is still not explained**].

Coming to EMS, a person can achieve it once he **discards his own eyes** and uses his sibling's ones. That is the mechanism of achieving EMS. Therefore if the person is closely related to the one who he would take the eye from, then there is a greater percentage of activating EMS.
Hope I have answered your question now

**IInd EDIT**

Thanks [Krazer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/krazer) for the updating the title of the question.From the title,I can come to a conclusion that no evidence as of now being cited related related to working of sharingan once it is transplanted.

Comment: Does this mean it is a total transplatation and a fusion as stated in point 2 of the question ? As for the main question, how it is realized the "fusion" of 2 different eyes in one eye hole?

Comment: yeah...I wasn't expecting this kind of answer..it's not kind of proper one,I'm used to get better ones from you @Kakashi...practically you've explained me what's the role of the MS

Comment: @Rinneg4n check out the updated edit....hope it answers to your question......

Comment: well,I really don't like the modification of the questions title, since I'm less interested in random sharingan transplantation, but more likely in the MS and the exact role,being curious fir this part,as @Dimitri mx said: "How do the eyes exactly fuse? and how do they put 2 pairs of eyes in a body to begin with? Guess this is a sort of anime magic "

Comment: @Rinneg4n exatly...... can't comeup with concrete answers since it's not disclosed in the anime or in manga properly :'(

Comment: @Kakashi I know that we can't find a proper answer,but I'm simply revolted by this....I mean...at last,we all are talking about the EMSharingan

Answer (score 0):

I think the sharingan transplanted to the new user recognise the bloodties and therefore grants the new user some new abilities like the perfect Susanoo

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A about anime & manga. While this might be true, could you provide some sources/references to support your answer? Pure speculation or personal theory is discouraged. You can always [edit] to improve your post. Also, consider taking a [tour] to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

You are all wrong I'm sorry lol the mangekyo awakens a chakra in the brain after a tragedy or loss of love ect that chakra is transferred to the ocular receptors from the brain which is why the eyes change shape and color so therefore when you transfer eyes the new eyes have the old host power engraved in the and you sharingan is written in your brain so it fuses with new eyes it was all staed in old Naruto episodes not sure exactly one

Comment: Hi. While this might be common knowledge for some, it might not be for others. Please provide specific sources for your answers, especially if it is a counter-argument, since these serve as proof. As it looks like now, it requires others to verify the information you stated. Please provide answers that do not require others to check if it's false or not. Thanks :)